# nuxt lazy load plugin with vue 2.6.12

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lazy-loading

i was built simple vue js plugin(wrapper on [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/basics.html)) and want to include it when component hydrate and loaded, however facing issue from vue which not allow to register components after app was inited. Can someone provide solution how i can pass this issue?

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="scriptLoaded">
    <validated-input/> <!--  injected from plugin.js -->
    <autocomplete-input/>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      scriptLoaded: false,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    if (process.client && !window.scriptValidatedInputLoaded) {
      window.scriptValidatedInputLoaded = true;

      const ValidatedInput = await import('plugin.js');
      Vue.use(ValidatedInput.default);
      this.scriptLoaded = true;
    }
  },
}; 
</script>
```

plugin.js

```
import AutoCompleteInput from './components/AutoCompleteInput.vue';
import ValidatedInput from './components/ValidatedInput.vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
import MaskedInput from 'vue-masked-input';
import VueMask from 'v-mask';

import 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css';

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
 
    Vue.component('autocomplete-input', AutoCompleteInput);
    Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);
 
    Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
      inject: ['$validator'],
      fieldsBagName: 'veeFields',
    });

    Vue.component('MaskedInput', MaskedInput);
    Vue.use(VueMask);
    Vue.component('validated-input', ValidatedInput);
  },
};
```

page.vue

```
<template>
  <MyComponent/><!-- will load and render only when user visit the page-->
</template>
<script>
export default{
      components: {
      MyComponent: () => import('../MyComponent'),
    },
}
</script>
```

error in console
`Unknown custom element: <validated-input> - did you register the component correctly?`

Answer (score 0):

update your code like so:

MyComponent.vue:
Use Vue's async component loading for the components.

```
<template>
<div>
    <validated-input/> <!-- injected from plugin.js -->
    <autocomplete-input/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
// ...
};
</script>
```

plugin.js:
Remove the component registrations from the install function.

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

export default {
install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    fieldsBagName: 'veeFields',
    });
},
};
```

page.vue:
Use async component loading for MyComponent.

```
<template>
<MyComponent/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
components: {
    MyComponent: () => import('../MyComponent'),
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: tnx for your advise, but i cant import component which was registered in my plugin, i need my wrappers which i was registered during install in plugin.js